# Assign to a null pointer an area inside a function and preserve the value outside

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function that reads from a socket, it returns a `char**` where packets are stored and my intention is to use a `NULL` `unsigned int` pointer where I store the length of single packet.

```
char** readPackets(int numToRead,unsigned int  **lens,int socket){

    char** packets=(char**)malloc(numToRead);
    int *len=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numToRead);

    *(lens)=len;

    for(int i=0;i<numToRead;i++){
        //read
        packets[i]=(char*)malloc(MAX_ETH_LEN);
        register int pack_len=read(socket,packets[i],MAX_ETH_LEN);

        //TODO handler error in  case of freezing

        if(pack_len<=0){
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        len[i]=pack_len;
    }


    return packets;

}
```

I use it in this way:

```
unsigned int *lens_out=NULL;
char **packets=readPackets(N_PACK,&lens,sniff_sock[handler]);
```

where `N_PACK` is a constant defined previously.

Now the problem is that when I am inside the function everything works, in fact `*(lens)` points to the same memory area of `len` and outside the function `lens_out` points to the same area too. Inside the function `len[i]` equals to `*(lens[i])` (I checked it with gdb).

The problem is that outside the function even if `lens_out` points to the same area of `len` elements with same index are different for example

```
len[0]=46
lens_out[0]=4026546640
```

Can anyone explain where I made the mistake?

Comment: `char** packets=(char**)malloc(numToRead);` is suspicious.  I'd expect `.... malloc(sizeof *packets * numToRead);`

Comment: i use bytes so sizeof(char)=1 so i think that is uselesse in this case

Comment: `sizeof(char)=1 ` is true but does not apply here. `packets` is a `char **`, not a `char *`.  `char** packets = ... malloc(...)`  is attempting to allocate memory  for a number of pointers, not a number of `char`.

Comment: Yes thanks i missed sizeof (char*)

Comment: Consider using `malloc(sizeof *pointer *n)` rather than `malloc(sizeof (type_of_pointer)*n)`.  It is easier to code correctly (as our comments discussed), review and maintain.

Comment: @P.Carlino yes but please don't change the question, it invalidates the comments. Rolled back.

Comment: Post the code that prints `len[0]=46
lens_out[0]=4026546640`

Comment: [don't cast malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement `char** packets=(char**)malloc(numToRead)` for sure does not reserve enough memory. Note that an element of `packets`-array is of type `char*`, and that `sizeof(char*)` is probably `8` (eventually `4`), but very very unlikely `1`. So you should write

```
char** packets = malloc(sizeof(char*) * numToRead)
```

Otherwise, you write out of the bounds of reserved memory, thereby yielding undefined behaviour (probably the one you explained).

Note further that with `i--; continue;`, you get memory leaks since you assign a new memory block to the ith element, but you lose reference to the memory reserved right before.  Write `free(packets[i]);i--;continue;` instead.

Further, `len[0]` is an integral type, whereas `lens[0]` refers to a pointer to int. Comparing these two does not make sense.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sizeof(char*) * numToRead`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to put it out there that you should *write clear code for the sake of future maintenance*, and not for what you *think* is *optimal* (yet). This entire function should merely be replaced with `read`. That's the crux of my post.

---

> Now the problem is that when I am inside the function everything works

I disagree. On a slightly broader topic, the biggest problem here is that you've posted a question containing code which doesn't compile when copied and pasted unmodified, and the question isn't about the error messages, so we can't answer the question without *guessing*.

My *guess* is that you haven't noticed these error messages; you're running *a stale binary* which we don't have the source code for, we can't reproduce the issue and we can't see the *old* source code, so we can't help you. It is as valid as any other guess. For example, there's another answer which speculates:

> Your statement `char** packets=(char**)malloc(numToRead)` for sure does not reserve enough memory.

The `malloc` manual doesn't guarantee that precisely `numToRead` bytes will be allocated; in fact, allocations to processes tend to be performed in *pages* and just as the `sleep` manual doesn't guarantee a precise number of milliseconds/microseconds, it may allocate more or it may allocate less; in the latter case, `malloc` must return `NULL` which **your code needs to check**.

It's extremely common for implementations to seem to *behave correctly* when a *buffer* is overflowed anyway. Nonetheless, it'd be best if you fixed that buffer overflow. `malloc` doesn't know about the type you're allocating; you need to tell it *everything* about the size, not just *the number of elements*.

P.S. You probably want `select` or `sleep` within your loop, you know, to "handle error in case of freezing" or whatever. Generally, OSes will switch context to another program when you call one of those, and only switch back when there's data ready to process. By calling `sleep` after sending or receiving, you give the OS a heads up that it needs to perform some I/O. The ability to choose that timing can be beneficial, when you're optimising. Not at the moment, though.

---

> Inside the function `len[i]` equals to `*(lens[i])` (I checked it with gdb).

I'm fairly sure you've misunderstood that. Perhaps `gdb` is implicitly dereferencing your pointers, for you; that's really irrelevant to C (so don't confuse anything you learn from gdb with anything C-related).

In fact, I strongly recommend learning a little bit less about `gdb` and a lot more about `assert`, because the former won't help you document your code for future maintenance from other people, including us, those who you ask questions to, where-as the latter will. If you include `assert` in your code, you're almost certainly strengthening your question (and code) much more than including `gdb` into your question would.

The types of `len[i]` and `*(len[i])` are different, and their values are affected by the way types are interpreted. These values can only be considered *equal* When they're converted to the same type. We can see this through [C11/3.19p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19p1) (the definition of "value", where the standard establishes it is dependant upon *type*). `len[i]` is an `int *` value, where-as `*(len[i])` is an `int` value. The two categories of values might have different alignment, representation and... well, they have different semantics entirely. One is for integral data, and the other is a reference to an object or array. You **shouldn't** be comparing them, no matter *how* equal they may seem; the information you obtain from such a comparison is virtually useless.

You can't use `len[i]` in a multiplication expression, for example. They're certainly not *equal* in that respect. They might *compare* equal (as a side-effect of comparison introducing implicit conversions), which is useless information for you to have, and that is a different story.

`memcmp((int[]){0}, (unsigned char[]){ [sizeof int] = 42 }, sizeof int)` may return 0 indicating that they're equal, but you know that array of characters contains an extra byte, right? Yeh... they're *equal*...

---

**You *must* check the return value of `malloc` (and [*don't cast the return value*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))**, if you're using it, though I *really* think you should reconsider your options with that regard.

The fact that you use `malloc` means everyone who uses your function must then use `free`; it's locking down-stream programmers into an anti-pattern that can tear the architecture of software apart. You should separate categories of *allocation logic* and *user interface logic* from *processing logic*.

For example, you use `read` which gives you the opportunity to choose whatever storage duration you like. This means you have an immense number of optimisation opportunities. It gives you, the downstream programmer, the opportunity to write flexible code which assigns whatever storage duration you like to the memory used. Imagine if, on the other hand, you had to *free* every return value from every function... That's the mess you're encouraging.

This is especially a poor, inefficient design when constants are involved (i.e. your usecase), because you could just use an automatic array and get rid of the calls to `malloc` and `free` altogether... Your downstream programmers code could be:

```
char packet[size][count];
int n_read = read(fd, packet, size * count);
```

Perhaps you think using `malloc` to allocate (and later read) `n` spaces for packets is faster than using something else to allocate `n` spaces. You should test that theory, because from my experience computers tend to be optimised for simpler, shorter, more concise logic.

In anticipation:

> But I can't `return packet;` like that!

True. You can't `return packet;` to your downstream programmer, so you modify an object pointed at by an argument. That doesn't mean you should use `malloc`, though.

Unfortunately, too many programs are adopting this "use `malloc` everywhere" mentality. It's reminiscent of the "don't use `goto`" crap that we've been fed. Rather than listening to cargo cult propaganda, I recommend thinking critically about what you hear, because your peers are in the same position as you; they don't necessarily know what they're talking about.